# How to position listview to exactly where it was left of before app destruction?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a listfragment and instagram-like photo feed. How to retain position of the listview so that next time app starts it showed listview exactly where and as it was left of?

Edit: I was planning to write to sharedPreferences position of the listview in onPause and then get them onCreate and set listview's position via setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y). But then I don't know how to obtain y. If I would put y = 0, then the view at that position would be seen first thing, i.e. on top of the screen. But that's not necessarily the case all the time. The view might be left of at the middle of the screen last time

Answer (score 1):

I think the most accurate way to get the position of the Listview is from **setOnScrollListener**:

```
    ListView listview = getListView();

    listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    ...
    }
```

Notes:

- Save the firstVisibleItem value onto sharedPreferences in `onScroll` method.
- `getListView` method can be used when ListFragment is subclassed.
- I used `listview.setSelection` method for setting a certain row position in Listview, and that is sufficient.
- Lastly, setOnScrollListener is performance efficient. I do not notice any performance lag.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in Android you will have absolutely no idea when the app is closed since there are no events you can listen to for this purpose.

Because of this, you should periodically (or in your scroll listener) keep writing the position of the visible item in the list view in a shared preference (ideally on a background thread to allow smooth scrolling) or an internal database and then when the app is started, check the value and position your list view correctly.

I don't think there's any other way to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: I was planning to write to sharedPreferences position of the listview in onPause and then get them onCreate and set listview's position via setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y). But then I don't know how to obtain y. If I would put y = 0, then the view at that position would be seen first thing, i.e. on top of the screen. But that's not necessarily the case all the time. The view might be left of at the middle of the screen last time

Comment: That's not what I would do. Imagine you have a 100 items in your listview and the "last browsed item" is the 98th item with the `id=12345`. What I would save would be `12345` (the id of the view I'm displaying) and then when the user brings up the screen, search my list, find the position of that item with that id and then set the selection of the listview to that. What you should use is `setSelection(position)` instead of `setSelectionFromTop()`

Comment: Yes,but that will show the item with id 12345 in the very beginning of screen, while that item might have been close to the middle or bottom or anywhere else in the screen before app was destroyed.